# Uncaught TypeError: TransportU2F.create is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, blockchain

I'm getting the error Uncaught TypeError: TransportU2F.create is not a function when attempting to use https://github.com/LedgerHQ/ledgerjs/tree/master/packages/hw-transport-u2f

Specifically I've done:

```
    import TransportU2F from "@ledgerhq/hw-transport-u2f";
    TransportU2F.create().then(transport => console.log("hey"));
```

This should work as it's the example they give.  I've tried various versions of this with node and in my browser imported into an html file.

I've also tried listing the methods for TransportU2F.  create is not listed.  I'm not sure why.

Appreciate any help.  Thanks.

Comment: If you can, show us minimal example that doesn't work. Your code is ok so there must be something else that cuases this error.

Comment: seems like docs is outdated, there is `open` method in source code of `TransportU2F` module, try using it instead of `create`

Comment: Same problem with open.  When I list all the objects methods I get only ["TransportError", "TransportStatusError", "getAltStatusMessage", "default"]